# Send email-specific links in PHP

Tags: php, email, hyperlink

I'm trying to make an unsubscribe link in my PHP emails- however, I'd like the links to be specific to the email that they're sent to. For example, if I sent the email to "joe@example.org", I'd want the link to be something like "example.org/unsubscribe.php?joe@example.org". (I realize this isn't secure- I'd make it a string of characters)

I tried using an array- however, I received an error

```
Warning: mail() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given on line 51
```

This was my code:

```
$to = array("example@example.org,example2@example.org");
```

I know this is possible- most emails from large companies have unsubscribe links which track the email that's to be unsubscribed. How is this done? Do they use the method outlined above, or do they send individual emails?

Comment: Can you show the code you already have? We can probably help you plug in what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, to fix your first error, don't use an array in your $to, make it a string (just remove your `array()`).

As for doing the *unsubscribe*, usually what you want is to have a link that will point to a page on your site, and then you can add something to the end of that link, as you stated.

The easiest example is something like `unsubscribe.php?email=john.doe@gmail.com`.

If you want to obscure it a bit you can `base64` encode it, then on your unsubscribe page you would `base64` decode that, then use that to do a lookup in your table. You could also use multiple metrics, such as the email, user id, maybe a unique id that references the email you sent out... it all depends on your application, but you'd want to do something to prevent someone from just updating your query string and launching it at your unsubscribe page.

*Base64 encode/decode* is not in any way secure, it just obscures the data for more casual users.

Comment: However, how can you customize the link for each user?

Comment: When you go to send the email, grab whatever you need for the unsubscribe side and build your unsubscribe URL into the body of the email.

Comment: ? I don't think you understood. I'm going to send the email to more than one person. How can I make the link specific to the email it was sent to?

Comment: Ok, so if you're going to send the email to more than one person, I assume you're doing so in a loop? So you would do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/hrb087ps/

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. However, how would I decode the base 64 in the unsubscribe page?

Comment: How would I only decode that certain part of the url?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131076/discussion-between-j-d-and-zackh105).

Answer (score 0):

you probably have something like this in your code:

```
mail($to);
```

try something like:

```
mail($to[0]);
```

or

```
mail($to[1]);
```

or when you have an array with emails you all want to unsubscribe from:

```
$to = array("mail@mail.com", "mail1@mail.com", "mail2@mail.com");

foreach($mail in $to) {
    mail($mail);
}
```

or just make `$to` a string instead of an array, which would be much better even.

but if you need to use an array, use the code snippets I gave above.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of an unsubscribe link. I know how to send emails- however, I don't know how to send emails with user-specific links

Comment: it solves your error, atleast from what I understood from your question

Comment: It does- however, my question was how to send user specific links. Using an array was one method I tried- however, I don't know if that's a good method. I was asking for help in giving me a method of making user links, not just fixing the error